# How to use a T-SQL UDF in a SELECT or UPDATE statement?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

Context: SQL Server 2000

I've written a UDF that gives me the text between two other texts, viz

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StrBetween 
(
    @Text nvarchar(4000),
    @Lhs nvarchar(4000),
    @Rhs nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LhsOffset INT;
    DECLARE @RhsOffset INT;
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @LhsOffset = CHARINDEX( @Lhs, @Text );
    IF @LhsOffset = 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN @Text;
    END
    SET @Result = SUBSTRING( @Text, @LhsOffset+1, LEN(@Text)-LEN(@Lhs));
    SET @RhsOffset = CHARINDEX( @Rhs, @Result );
    IF @RhsOffset = 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN @Result;
    END
    SET @Result = SUBSTRING( @Result, 1, @RhsOffset - 1 );
    RETURN @Result;
END
```

This works fine in SQL Query Analyser if I have, say,

```
SELECT dbo.StrBetween('dog','d','g')
```

However, when I pass a column in as the value of the first argument, I get no response. For example,

```
SELECT [TEST].[dbo].StrBetween(Referrer,'//', '/') as tst FROM tblTest
```

Referrer is declared as an nvarchar field. I'm a newbie when it comes to T-SQL. What obvious thing am I not seeing?

Comment: what is Referrer content?

Comment: Can you clarify 'Get no response'? Do you get an error or incorrect data returned?

Comment: Your function doesn't work for `SELECT dbo.StrBetween('http://bbc.co.uk/default.html','//', '/')` try testing it with your actual data.

Comment: Please don't do edits like that. You changed your question such that the bug no longer appeared (and then, appeared to blame the *corrected* line in your update). In short, it made your question read like nonsense, and would not help any future readers.

Comment: Fair comment, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I shall unfix.

Comment: Oh, you've already unfixed the fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an issue with calling - it's a logic issue, and the fact that your `@Rhs` value is part of the `@Lhs` value.

```
SET @Result = SUBSTRING( @Text, @LhsOffset+1, LEN(@Text)-LEN(@Lhs));
```

This is removing the *first* character of your `@Lhs` string. However, since the second character is `/`, and that's what your `@Rhs` match is searching for, it immediately finds it at position 1 and so you get an empty string.

Instead, try:

```
SET @Result = SUBSTRING( @Text, @LhsOffset+LEN(@Lhs), 4000);
```

You don't have to be exact with computing a length. If you ask for 4000 characters and the string is only 12 characters long, `SUBSTRING` will give you back at most 12 characters. So don't bother computing the new length.